# Uncaught ReferenceError: django is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, widget

I'm trying to use the Admin Widgets with a couple of DateField on my formulary but only the first of them gets the widget displayed correctly, for the other one I get an error:

> DateTimeShortcuts.js:205 Uncaught ReferenceError: django is not defined

(The line indicated is:

```
django.jQuery(document).bind('keyup', function(event) {
```

)

Here's my template head:

```
<head>
{% load adminmedia  %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css"/>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/global.css"/> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/widgets.css"/>
{{ form.media }}...
```

My model fields:

```
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()
```

And my form class:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget
        )
    end_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget
        )
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

I guess it some kind of rendering rule but I'm totally confused. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried including the form's media via a 'Media' class as described in the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#s-media-as-a-static-definition

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`django.jQuery` is defined in `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js` and relies on `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/jquery.js`. You need to load those js files in your template directly

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
```

Or include those files in [your form media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#media-on-forms)

Also check the `media` property of `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: Note that in recent versions of Django, jQuery is located at `vendor/jquery/jquery.js` instead of `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: Actually, in Django 1.11 the file is located at `vendor/jquery` in the full as well as the minified version. (See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L582)

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by this way:

```
class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):
    class Media:
        js = ('admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js', 'admin/js/jquery.init.js')
```