# Django admin's filter_horizontal not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm wrote this code:

admin.py

```
class MarketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['Name', 'Location']
    ordering = ['id', 'Name']
    filter_horizontal = ["Weekend"]

admin.site.register(Market, MarketAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class Market(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, verbose_name=u'Название')
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, verbose_name=u'Страна')
    Weekend = models.ManyToManyField(Weekend, verbose_name=u'Выходной')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'"Финансовый рынок"'
        verbose_name_plural = u"Финансовые рынки"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.Name, self.Location)
```

Using unicode for verbose names didnt help to recreate weekend field at horizontal filter. Why is this happening?

UPD:
This was given console at my browser:

> [17:33:41.392] ReferenceError: grp is not defined
>   [17:33:41.395] ReferenceError: grp is not defined
>   [17:33:41.420] ReferenceError: django is not defined
>   [17:33:41.524] not defined property «box-sizing».
>   [17:33:41.569] ReferenceError: SelectFilter is not defined

Comment: What version of Django? Have you run `syncdb`?

Comment: Also, make sure you are loading jQuery in your template...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583652