# JavaScript file not loaded in Django custom admin page

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, media

I added a custom page containing a form in my Django admin site.
To do this, I wrote this code:

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    class Media:
        js = ('js/foo.js',)

    my_number = forms.IntegerField(
        required=True,
        min_value=1,
        max_value=10,
        label='Magic number'
    )
```

And this code:

```py
form = MyForm()
context = self.each_context(request)
context.update({'form': form})
return render(request, 'admin/players/foo.html', context)
```

My problem is the JS does not execute/load because if I put the following single line in it, nothing happens:

```js
alert('foo');
```

What's strange is I have a very similar thing somewhere else and it works like a charm:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('bar1', 'bar2',)
    search_fields = ('bar1',)

    class Media:
        js = ('js/bar.js',)
```

I checked the `media` property in both cases and I got this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/foo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bar.js"></script>
```

So at least, the path to the file is OK.

What did I miss?

**UPDATE:**
Following the accepted answer, I added the following lines in my template:

```
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Both files appear under `utils` folder. But you are trying to import it as `js/foo.js`. Did you try to change it like `js/utils/foo.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `{{form.media}}` into `foo.html` template.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops... My JS loads but now I get the "django is not defined" error... Do you happen to know the solution to this problem as well?

Comment: @Rodolphe check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583652/uncaught-referenceerror-django-is-not-defined

Comment: Thanks. It indeed does the trick. But I'm surprised I didn't need to manually include jquery when I customized my other page. It was automatically included... Thanks anyway!